# counting the number of times one word has been typed in

Tags: c

after numerous attempts to make my program work I turn to you guys. I want to make a program that counts the numbers of times a specific word has been typed in. That specific word has been specified as an argument and I'm trying to recall it by using argc and argv. Then I want the program to count the number of times I type in a word and to finish I want to be able to type in #EOF so it stops and shows me the result. This is what I have been trying on so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i=0;
char buf[1026]={'\0'};
char *p="#EOF\n";
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

while((strcmp(buf, p) !=0) && (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL ))
{

   if(strncmp(buf, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
}
printf("%d", i);

return 0;
}
```

I get no errors at all, but nothing really happens either. I did try to check where the fault lies, and I found out that when I try to display the value of I within the if statement it's counting very very very fast!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop.

```
fgets(buf, 1025, stdin);
```

In the above line of code, `fgets()` will take from `stdin` a string of characters ***including the newline character*** and store it into `buf`.

A simple fix to that is to add the newline character into the string you check against:

```
char *p="#EOF\n";
```

---

Other issues:

1)

```
char buf[1026]; // This should be initialized to an empty string when you start
                // char buf[1026] = {'\0'}; would do it
char *p="#EOF";

while(strcmp(buf, p) !=0)
```

2) Because you used a `while()` loop, and you're checking before getting any input, you'll always enter it at least once. This might not be what you wanted to do. A `do`/`while` loop, or grabbing the input as the first step would be better.

3) `if(strncmp(buf, argv[0],` this is checking against the name of your program, if you wanted to check against the first command line argument you wanted `argv[1]`

4) If you're trying to check that the first command line argument is the same as what the user is typing you want this:

```
if(strncmp(buf, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
```

---

My version of your code that's working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i=0;
    char buf[1026]={'\0'};
    char *p="#EOF\n";
    do
    {
       fgets(buf, 1025, stdin);
       if(strncmp(buf, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
            i++;
    } while (strcmp(buf, p) != 0);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MichelWervers - Happy to help. Since you're new to SO, I'll just mention that if your Question is solved by one of the answers, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark by the answer. It's nice to let others know you have a solution.

Comment: oke I will thank you! only one problem left and thats the actual counting; it remains 1 whatever I do :(

Comment: @MichelWervers - take a look at my #4 above, maybe the check is failing. Are you using GCC to compile?

Comment: yes I use GCC to compile. when I use your code my i = 0 when it prints.

Comment: @MichelWervers - Your code's while loop condition is still wrong. Check out the do/while in my above edit.

Comment: if I copy/paste your code the program crashes but when I change my program to it it works :S but still, it only counts the first time you inputted  word every line. if i type in the same word 5x on one line it counts only 1

Comment: @MichelWervers - on one **line**? Like if I called it "./a.out hi" you want to give input: "hi hi hi" and have it count that as 3?

Comment: @MichelWervers - OK... that's a totally different program. Now you're looking for substrings, `strcmp` is not equipped to handle that. This code works if your input is `hi<enter key>` `hi<enter key>` etc, it correctly counts it, but if you want it to be an number of substrings that's different. You should move that to a new question. Take a look at "substring" and "strtok" and see if you can do it. If not, make a new Question showing what you tried. That's changing too much of the original question as none of the current code or answers are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first problem is that argv[0] is the name of your program; your parameters start at argv[1].

Also, your while loop is being invoked before you put anything into buf.  You definitely need to either use a different loop or initialize buf before-hand to ensure your loop behaves properly.

Also, I recommend making sure that you know exactly what should and should not match.  You are doing a substring comparison (strncmp) based on the length of the word to be searched for, but is this what you want?  This will get the word in a substring, but do you want that, or the whole word?  Also, will the user just type in a word on each line or a sentence in which the word may occur?  Is case important?

Comment: what do you mean by "setting buf to the empty string"? what I want to achieve is by example: I type in: hello hello (enter) hello hello (enter) #EOF and then it counts the times I typed in hello so 4 times in this case

Comment: Actually, I nixed that part :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be:

```
while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL )
{
}
```

It doesn't make sense to check that the buffer is non-empty *before* the `fgets()`.

Note that `fgets()` will include the line feed, see [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). Also note use of `sizeof` to avoid the use of magical numbers in the code.

If you want the user to really type <kbd>#EOF</kbd> to end, rather than ending the input by "sending" the end-of-file signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) in Windows) which will work and cause the loop to exit, you msut of course compare against that before counting the word(s) in the line.

Comment: I really want the user to type in #EOF. I now have the following: `
 while((strcmp(buf, p) !=0) && (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL ))
`